# Terminal windows don't show up in alt-tab

Tags: 12.04, compiz

I've seen a few of the other questions regarding this topic, and the suggestion to install `compiz-settings-manager` and select application switcher worked, it just showed both application switchers over each other. Is there another work-around?

Comment: Did you check out ring-switcher in ccsm? Besides, Alt+Tab started working for me after a few restarts of my system. It certainly does not work right away. I'm using 12.04 Gnome Classic.

Comment: @harisibrahimkv You should write that as an answer, because for some reason - a few restarts later - it shows up just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Gnome classic in 12.04, try a few restarts of your system. The Alt+Tab behavior usually starts working fine after a few restarts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using 12.04, but Unity. Still, after a few restarts the problem went "poof"